# Site Template- Publishing Template

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing

It doesn't matters which page or which blog or which book I am reading. Everywhere I get to know that "**Publish is the feature which allows other users to view a file which has been published.**" That is so obvious! I know what `"Publish"` means. 
**I want to know what a visitor can see** in a published site, which he isn't able to see on the other sites like `Collaboration`, `Enterprise` or `Duet Enterprise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A SharePoint publishing site is a site that’s built using a publishing site template. It’s a site where authoring and publishing are more structured and where content management processes are enforced.
- Publishing sites are typically used to create enterprise intranets, communication portals, and public websites.
- Publishing sites have unique features that streamline the authoring, approving, and publishing processes. These features are enabled automatically when you create a publishing site and include page layouts, column types, web parts, lists, and libraries.

Check also the diff [between Team Site and Publishing Site](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/difference-between-team-site-and-publishing-site)

Comment: Dear @TusharAnand. I am also here if you need more clarification.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get the difference. I know one of them i.e., by default everyone in the team site has got same permissions but this isn't the same in case of a publishing site. But what else is different?

Comment: Dear , I mentioned in my a nswer that Publishing sites have unique features that streamline the authoring, approving, and publishing processes. These features are enabled automatically when you create a publishing site and include page layouts, column types, web parts, lists, and libraries.

Comment: what else you need to know :) kindly tell me i only try to help you

Comment: Isn't there any private messaging features in stack exchange? I have got a bunch of dumb questions!

Comment: wait I will create a chat room

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43414/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-site-template-publishing-template).

Answer (score 1):

Collaboration Site, Enterprise Site or Duet Enterprise Site are not proper names of site templates but even if they were, you do not see what other people can view/edit by the name of the site template but by the permission structure of every single site or every single element (list, library) or every single item (document, page, item). To be able to do that you need to understand permission structure in sharepoint.

The fact that it is a publishing site or not is irrelevant, the permission structure works by the same logic on every site.

Comment: I hope, I wrote the correct names this time. But still I didn't get a thing ! -.-' Is SharePoint this hard to understand?

Comment: I think you need to visualize this answer, rather than reading, here is a video that explaines sharepoint basics, there are many others on you tube, especially that talk about permissions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsfUNRRu0VY